# How to count values in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, count, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm new to pl/sql and I'm trying to count all the employees that have the initials 'H'

 My code currently looks like this but I get an error on line 24, `COUNT(v_initials);`

```
declare

    cursor cursor_employee
    is 
    select * from cmp_employer_employees
    where rownum < 25
    order by employer_employee_id asc
    ;
    
    v_initials varchar(100);
    v_count number := 0;
    
begin
    
    for r_employee in cursor_employee loop
    
        v_initials := r_employee.INITIALS;
    
        if v_initials like '%H' 
        then
        
            COUNT(v_initials);
        
        end if;
    
    end loop;

end;
```

Comment: You would never really do this in pl/sql as it’s so well optimized in SQL. However, instead of `count` (which is not a pl/sql statement) you can just declare a numeric variable (in the `declare` part) and increment it by one each time the `if` condition is evaluated as true. Remember you have a `rownum` filter in your query so you won’t be counting all the matching rows unless there are less than 25 rows in your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop there - you could query `count(*)` from the table with a condition:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   employees
WHERE  initials LIKE '%H'
```

**EDIT**
To answer the question in the comment, you can use an insert-select statement to collect these employees to another table:

```sql
INSERT INTO employees_with_h
SELECT * 
FROM   employees
WHERE  initials LIKE '%H'
```

Or, if you want just a few specific columns:

```sql
INSERT INTO employees_with_h (target_col1, target_col2, etc)
SELECT col1, col2, etc
FROM   employees
WHERE  initials LIKE '%H'
```

Comment: Yea I know but is it possible to use sql in an if statement?

Comment: Maybe insert into a new table if initials are 'H'?